# Why is discrete time quantum walks applicable only for undirected graphs?

Tags: quantum-walks

I don't understand how this property of discrete-time quantum walk relates to the property that the transition operator SC is unitary. Many papers mention this and continue without explaining.
Suppose we have a directed graph, Let us give separate coin space for every vertex, if we have vertex A pointing to B and B not to A we can just not take the basis $d$ corresponding to the direction of the edge AB in the coin space of B. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Another reasoning I thought: Since we define an operator $U$ which is unitary on the graph, this means $U^\dagger$ (conjugate transpose) is also an operator that is defined on the graph (sorry if this is very wrong). So if $U$ takes the walker from A to B. Then $U^\dagger$ should take it from B to A. Which is not possible if the edge is directed.

I have spent a lot of time on this and can't seem to come to a good conclusion, please help.

**EDIT**: Szegedy's walk is discrete-time quantum walk(DTQW) but can be applied on a directed graph, it uses no coin space, so is the coin space the reason why DTQW is not possible on a directed graph?

Comment: please help me, any hint helps